# hyperlink button in an exact position

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I want to include a hyperlink button on a slide that is completely covered by a figure. If I do the following:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3in]{map}
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
    \hyperlink{inthispaper}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}        
\end{flushright}
\end{frame}
```

the button will not appear on the slide. Is there an environment that allows the button to float on the slide? Or is there a way to set the position of the button exactly?

Comment: You could wrap the `\hyperlink` inside a `\raisebox{<len>}{...}` to raise/lower it by `<len>`, thereby moving it up over your map. Also wrapping it inside a `\smash` would remove any subsequent height additions. So, perhaps try `\smash{\raisebox{<len>}{\hyperlink{..}{...}}}` (not tested).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package to place material at absolute positions on a page:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3in,height=3.6in]{map}
\end{center}
\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(.95\textwidth,-0.5\textheight)%
    \hyperlink{inthispaper}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}        
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` replaces the actual figure with a black rectangle; do not use that line in your actual code.