# How to position beamer button exactly?

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I would like to know how to position a beamer button at the same position on each single slide independently from the slide content. Refering to [hyperlink button in an exact position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50643/hyperlink-button-in-an-exact-position) I assumed that I can use the following MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{map}
\end{center}
\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(.95\textwidth,-0.05\textheight)%
\hyperlink{inthispaper}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}        
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{test}

text

\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(0.95\paperwidth,0.95\paperheight)%
\hyperlink{inthispaper}{\beamerbutton{Back}}        
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the first frame is simply copied and pasted from the other question, while the second frame is elaborated by myself using

```
\paperwidth
```

in order to make LaTeX refer to the whole slide.

However, this does not work out the way I want to. Actually, I would like to have the button always on the spot at bottom right of the slide.

Is there a way to position a button exactly on the slide?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at the `eso-pic` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a possible solution where absolute position via `tikzpicture` environment `\node[<option>] (<label>) at (current page.south east){<content>}` is used.

[image]
[image]

Code

```
%\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,fragile,label=here]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3in,height=3in]{crocuses}
\end{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[shift={(-0.6cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
\hyperlink{there}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,label=there]{test}

text
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[shift={(-0.6cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
\hyperlink{here}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}};        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems like it takes little longer to compile...